# Pattern For Secondary JIT Features

Tags: usability, features

Lets say we are a picture saving service that allows you to save pictures you like from the community.  When a user takes the primary action of "liking" another person's photo we offer up secondary actions after the primary action is finished.  Does this seem like a good pattern for addressing Just-In-Time features like this?  Below is a screenshot of a mockup and the states.

[image]

Comment: FYI, you can now [import your Balsamiq mockups here](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/a/781/10478).

Comment: Hi Chad, can you explain what you mean by "JIT features"?

Comment: Does that mean Just In Time?

Comment: Yea Just In Time.  Sorry about the jargon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've come across a few websites that do something like that, and it seemed to work well. Experiment with the transitioning a bit and I'm sure it can work. It's nice to have the options available, but out of sight until "liked."

There will be some people who want to "add to collection" or "share" but don't want to "like" it first. That's the only downside I can think of, as long as you remember to show it by default for users without Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason the options can't always be present? What if a user thinks one of his friends might like the post and wants to share it with them. Instead of one-click share, he first has to like the picture (which he may not in fact actually like), and then share it.

Another bad case scenario is that the user wants to share something and has just started using the service. In this case, he may not know a share button pops up once he has liked a photo.

Comment: I think not showing them all at once could be good; prevents info overload and it's sort of gradual engagement